# Transform NFA to DFA

Tags: finite-automata, automata

I have simple example of NFA->DFA conversion, but I am confused about "q0,q1,q2" state. What is it for? Or maybe I have done something wrong?

Here it is:
[image]

Comment: Is there a question here?  States are states -- asking what they are "for" individually is not very meaningful.  What is the FA "for"?  Collectively the states and transitions make up a FA that recognizes some language on some alphabet.  Individually the states are just part of the automata.

Comment: Yeah, you are right - question might have not been clear ;d So, the question is - is that transformation (NFA->DFA) done correctly? FA accepts all strings which contains "ba" in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems you have done the transformation correctly.

But a correct result is not automatically the most efficient one. You could add "b" to the loop of state {q0, q2} and just delete the state {q0,q1,q2} with all the transitions that touch it. Both DFA accept the desired language.

Comment: Thank you bro :) Yea, I was thinking about the same (deleting {q0,q1,q2} state) :)